# piping pwd to an executable as an argument

Tags: command-line

So I have an alias for "sublime text" http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html
and very often I need to open a file or a folder right from the terminal, easy for a file:

```
subl myfile.html
```

and for a folder

```
subl /Users/me
```

But how can I use 'pwd' command to open current directory in sublime? Is there a way to pipe it in?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$(pwd)
```

or, you can use backticks, like

```
`pwd`
```

So:

```
subl `pwd`
```

Either way, what happens is the command `pwd` gets executed, then its return text gets passed as the command-line.  A good way to see what's happening, assuming you're using bash, is to issue `set -x` then run your command.  As this example, where `subl` is aliased to `echo` shows, the **result** of `pwd` is passed on the command-line to the expanded alias (lines beginning with `+` indicate the *actual* command being executed):

```
$ alias subl=echo
$ mkdir /tmp/abc
$ cd /tmp/abc
$ set -x
$ subl `pwd`
++ pwd
+ echo /tmp/abc
/tmp/abc
$
```

(When you're done, you can stop printing commands by issuing `set +x`.)

Comment: The backticks should be avoided, they've been deprecated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/shell-programming-whats-the-difference-between-command-and-command

Comment: @slm While backticks shouldn't be used in scripts, they're ok on the command line as long as you're typing simple stuff (no `\` or nested command substitution inside). They have the advantage of being easier to type and maintainability is only an issue in scripts.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the environmental variable PWD or the `.`

`sub1 $PWD`

`sub1 .`

Answer (score 1):

To interpolate the output of a command on the command line of another command, use [command substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution).

```
subl "$(pwd)/somefile.txt"
```

Note that you need to put `(…)` between double quotes. Otherwise, bad things will happen sometimes (when the output of the command contains whitespace or `\[*?`).

In the special case of `pwd`, there is a shell variable that contains the same text: instead of `$(pwd)`, you can write `$PWD`. For the same reasons, this needs to be between double quotes.

If you want `subl` to invoke the `subl` program with an absolute path as argument, this has to be done in a function, it can't be done in an alias. Remember that the path may already be an absolute path.

```
subl () {
  case "$1" in
    /*) :;; # already an absolute path, nothing to do
    *) set "$PWD/$1";; # make an absolute path
  esac
  command subl "$1"  # invoke the external program subl, even though a function exists
}
```